# Cant view lineage using UI for spline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spline-data-lineage-tracker

I have tried everything, the code even writes the data.
But spline is unable to pick it up.
My code runs sucessfully but there is no data in spline UI.

Spark - 3.3.1
Scala - 2.12.18
Python - 3.9.6
Spline agent - 1.1.0

Can someone guide me in this?

Initially was getting an error while submiting packages and conf in the spark submit command
but it went away when I wrote it in the script...

`spark-submit --packages za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.3-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:1.1.0 --conf "spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners=za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener" --conf "spark.spline.producer.url=http://localhost:8080/producer" pyspark_example.py`

CONVERTED TO:

`conf = SparkConf().set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "./spark-warehouse").set("spark.jars.packages", "za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.3-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:1.1.0").set("spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners", "za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener").set("spark.spline.producer.url", "http://localhost:8080/producer")`

Code:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext()

conf = SparkConf()
  .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "./spark-warehouse")
  .set("spark.jars.packages", "za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.3-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:1.1.0")
  .set("spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners", "za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener")
  .set("spark.spline.producer.url", "http://localhost:8080/producer")


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("employee").config(conf = conf).getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("employee.csv")
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("sample")`
```

Expected:

some output in SPLINE UI: http://localhost:9090/app/events/list

Instead Got: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UIZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this troubleshooting guide:
https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline/discussions/1225

It's important to check the logs and see if everything is initialized and working without errors.